# Apache RewriteRule on application hosted in subfolder leads to infinite loop

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, amazon-cloudfront

I'm currently hosting a PHP application on Apache. This application is behind a CloudFront distribution that sends all requests with `cms/*` to my application.

I used the following .htaccess file and hoped to make things work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /cms
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
</IfModule>


SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

I get an Internal Server Error and in the Apache Error logs this can be found:
`AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So, the URL being requested is `/cms/...`? Is Cloudfront mapped to the document root or the `/cms` subdirectory? What is your directory structure? Presumably, your CMS (and front-controller) is located in a `/cms` subdirectory (as per your directives)? However, with this setup I would have expected you to be using a `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory, not the document root?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, the url requested is `/cms/...`. Cloudfront is mapped to the document root of my Apache server. My CMS is running in the document root of the Apache server.

My frontend application is not hosted on this Apache server but in a S3 bucket. Cloudfront redirects all requests that are not `/cms/*` to this S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My CMS is running in the document root of the Apache server.

If the CMS is in the document root then you should remove the `RewriteBase /cms` directive entirely.

The presence of `RewriteBase /cms` results in the request being internally rewritten to `/cms/index.php` (not `/index.php`) and if this file does not exist then you will naturally get a rewrite-loop (the preceding condition checks that the request does not map to a file or directory).

In other words (with some additional improvements):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

`DirectoryIndex` is likely already set in the server config, although it is necessary here.

The first `RewriteRule` directive is an optimization to prevent unnecessary filesystem checks when the request is rewritten.

There is no need to traverse and capture the entire URL-path in the last `RewriteRule` directive (ie. `^(.*)`). The regex `.` (a single dot) is sufficient, and more efficient.

No need for the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper, unless these directives are *optional*.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it the following way:

I put the application on the Apache server in a `cms` folder and kept the current .htaccess as is. It might also work with keeping it in the Apache root folder and setting the RewriteBase to something like `../` if that works with Apache but I'm happy with the current solution.

Comment: If the application wasn't in the `/cms` subdirectory then that would certainly explain the rewrite loop, since `/cms/index.php` didn't exist. Alternatively, if the application is in the document root then simply remove the `RewriteBase /cms` directive entirely.